# Documents library - column that shows folders total size

Tags: 2013, 2010, document-library, column

My client wants a document library with folders representing contracts. In each folder there will be lots of files and my client would like to have a column that shows total files size inside each folder.

Do you know any (free or paid) solution that can do this in Sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 1):

In your view settings, scroll down to the "Totals" section and select the "Sum" of the "File Size" column:

[image: File Size Sum]